# can't access subdomain for laravel htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

On my domain public directory is the laravel public directory.so there is index.php and htaccess file. but i want to access `mydomain.com/demo/`, where `demo` is a folder.its always redirect me to my home page as `mydomain.com` because of route rewrite . so how can i access folders in mydomain.com. my `htaccess` is followed. ...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate .htaccess file within demo directory to override the .htaccess file in your root directory.

`Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all`

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate .htaccess (as Brian Dillingham said) file within demo directory to override the .htaccess file in your root directory.
But put use codes below instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also, you can refer the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38068912

Answer (score 0):

For the ones out there who use a public domain but the Laravel directory is within a subdirectory. You might have the following folder structure:

```
- / <-- directory your domain (e.g. "https://example.com") points to
- some_subfolder1/
- some_subfolder2/
- laravel_project/
    - ...
    - public/
        - .htaccess <-- File one has to modify
        - index.php
        - ...
```

The .htaccess File's `RewriteRule` for Front Controllers would look the following:

```
RewriteRule ^ laravel_project/public/index.php [L]
```

So you will end up with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ laravel_project/public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In addition, I also modified the `.env`-File for the `APP_URL` param:

```
APP_URL=https://example.com/laravel_project/public
```

Furthermore, you might think of moving the laravel project files (despite from the public folder) outside of this file tree.