# htaccess for domain and subdomain with laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a domain and subdomain to work on a shared hosting account. It is a Laravel 5.1 application.

My access file is

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I just purchased another domain and added it on, but I get a 500 error. I renamed the access file and then it worked. So it has something to do with the access file. Essentially I want two separate domains with and I'm wanting two separate laravel applications, one for each.

I'm not familiar with atacceess.

Comment: When you get a 500 error, look into Apache's error log file. Without a hint, nobody can help you.

Comment: There are no errors from the error log that I am seeing. The last error in the error_log file is from june 16th.

Comment: Essentially I have one main laravel website and it uses the laravel framework with the above code in the htaccess, but I also want to host another laravel web app on my subdomain. When I rename this file then the subdomain works, but if i keep it as is then it causes that error and doesn't allow access to my subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you get a redirect loop, because the rule isn't protected by a condition. Although the default htaccess of Laravel should already contain them.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Olaf Dietsche's answer does work for me.

Here is another thing I came upon a website that also worked just before I saw his post. I guess I was reading that this would send a 404 to that directory.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main-topdomain.com$ [NC]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdomain-folder/(.*)$
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

So along with this comes another question if anyone is in my boat. I have my subdirectory inside of my root directory.***

dlaugh.com/public_html

laravel folders and access**
inluding

```
app
bootstrap
config
database
etc...
```

but also I have my sub folder

```
    app
    bootstrap
    config
    database
    etc...
    **mysubdomain in that folder**
```

Is it better practice to put

```
-main_domain_folder and
-subdomain_folder
in public_html
and then the
/app
/config
/database
```

would be in the main_domain_folder rather than passing the subdomain through the main domain?